# Is this way of searching an enum acceptable

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to search an enum to see if a user-supplied string matches any of the values, so I created this.Would this be considered a good way of searching for an enum?

```
enum Month {JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC};

try {
    String A = "DECc";
    Month.valueOf(A);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Could not find an enum with the String you entered");
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes this is good.. the other option is "to string" all the enum elements and compare the string to them one by one:

```
for (Month m : Month.values()) {
    if (m.name().equals(A)) {
        //found
    }
}
```

but your way is really better...